Docker compose up failed to exceute when i run apache/airflow:2.6.0-python3.9 webserver
I want to implement streaming ingest data with apache airflow, postgres, kafka, spark and cassandra.
I get some error when i run my docker compose file, the webserver container is unhealthy and i don't know how fix it.
I've delete it and restart many times but it still not work
error
 ✔ Container data-engineering-spark-master-1  Running                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 ✔ Container cassandra                        Running                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container zookeeper                        Healthy                                                                                                                                    0.8s 
 ✔ Container data-engineering-spark-worker-1  Running                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container data-engineering-postgres-1      Running                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container broker                           Healthy                                                                                                                                    1.8s 
 ✔ Container schema-registry                  Healthy                                                                                                                                    1.8s 
 ✔ Container control-center                   Running                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 ✘ Container data-engineering-webserver-1     Error                                                                                                                                     92.0s 
 ✔ Container data-engineering-scheduler-1     Recreated                                                                                                                                  0.1s 
dependency failed to start: container data-engineering-webserver-1 is unhealthy

the container failed to start when i run it on wsl virtual env, but works on native windows system.
docker compose file
services:
  zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.0
      hostname: zookeeper
      container_name: zookeeper
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      healthcheck:
        test: ['CMD', 'bash', '-c', "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 2181"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5
      networks:
        - confluent

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
          condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "bash", "-c", 'nc -z localhost 9092' ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.4.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081/" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.4.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
      schema-registry:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081" 
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      CONFLIENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      PORT: 9021
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9021/health" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  webserver:
    image: apache/airflow:2.6.0-python3.9
    command: webserver
    entrypoint: ['/opt/airflow/script/entrypoint.sh']
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Sequential
      - AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
      - AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_SECRET_KEY=this_is_a_very_secured_key
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./script/entrypoint.sh:/opt/airflow/script/entrypoint.sh
      - ./requirements.txt:/opt/airflow/requirements.txt
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD-SHELL', "[ -f /opt/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - confluent

  scheduler:
    image: apache/airflow:2.6.0-python3.9
    depends_on:
      webserver:
         condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./script/entrypoint.sh:/opt/airflow/script/entrypoint.sh
      - ./requirements.txt:/opt/airflow/requirements.txt
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Sequential
      - AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
      - AIRFLOW_WEBSERVER_SECRET_KEY=this_is_a_very_secured_key
    command: bash -c "pip install -r ./requirements.txt && airflow db upgrade && airflow scheduler"
    networks:
      - confluent

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.0
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
    networks:
      - confluent

  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    networks:
      - confluent
  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    networks:
      - confluent

  cassandra_db:
    image: cassandra:latest
    container_name: cassandra
    hostname: cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    environment:
      - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=512M
      - HEAP_NEWSIZE=100M
      - CASSANDRA_USERNAME=cassandra
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra
    networks:
      - confluent
networks:
  confluent:

Is the image that i use the matter ?
here is the entrypoint script
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ -e "/opt/airflow/requirements.txt" ]; then
  $(command python) pip install --upgrade pip
  $(command -v pip) install --user -r requirements.txt
fi

if [ ! -f "/opt/airflow/airflow.db" ]; then
  airflow db init && \
  airflow users create \
    --username admin \
    --firstname admin \
    --lastname admin \
    --role Admin \
    --email admin@example.com \
    --password admin
fi

$(command -v airflow) db upgrade

exec airflow webserver


probably a duplicate question -- post

Most likely your requirements file is not complete/correct. Note that the airflow container references this file.
